# invariant violation text strings must be rendered within a text component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was working with code supplied from my university to practise with but it now throws up the error message 'invariant violation: text strings must be rendered within a text component' I have even completely made a new file to run it fresh with the original code but still get that error.

is there a reason as to why this has suddenly happened and how can i fix it please?

Thank you

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true }
  }

  componentWillMount () {
       const localMovieData = require('./assets/test.json');

       this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: localMovieData.movies,
        }, function () {

        });
  }

  _renderItem = (info) => {

    return <Text>{this.state.dataSource.map((movie, index) => (
        <p>Hello, {movie.title} from {movie.releaseYear}!</p>
    ))}</Text>
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}

          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

JSON Data

```
{
  "title": "The Basics - Networking",
  "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  "movies": [
    { "id": "1", "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
    { "id": "2", "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
    { "id": "3", "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
    { "id": "4", "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
    { "id": "5", "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share ./assets/test.json file?

Comment: Hi, I have added it to the post, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main culprit is the < p > primitive in the code. Since this is react-native, should use < Text > instead of < p > .

[You can test it here](https://snack.expo.io/@torresho/movies)

```
 _renderItem = (info) => {

    return <View>{this.state.dataSource.map((movie, index) => (
        <Text>Hello, {movie.title} from {movie.releaseYear}!</Text>
    ))}</View>
  }
```

[image]

Comment: perfect that has got it working! Can i just ask one last thing sorry, whats making it repeat the data over and over. how can i stop this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

It's recommended to use `componentDidMount` for api call because `componentWillMount` is deprecated. [reference](https://dev.to/torianne02/componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount-5f0n)

Code-
you can import like this

```
import data from './test.json';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state={
    dataSource:data
  }
 _renderItem = (info) => {
    return <Text>{this.state.dataSource.map((movie, index) => (
        <Text>Hello, {movie.title} from {movie.releaseYear}</Text>
    ))}</Text>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://snack.expo.io/@akhtarvahid/demo)

Comment: @Bpt26 use Text tag instead of p tag because p is web(reactjs) for supported and react native have their own tags.